# Counting Sheloshim for a chol hamoed death

Tags: halacha, number, mourning-aveilus, chol-hamoed

How long is the shloshim observed for a death which occurs during chol hamoed Pesach? Does one observe a full thirty days started from the funeral or is it shortened because of the chag?

Comment: Reuven, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: I edited out your final question about Lag Baomer, because it's really a separate question - may one observing Shloshim shave on Lag Baomer - that has nothing to do with whether shloshim started on Chol Hamoed. Please consider [ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)ing it as a separate question.

Answer (score 4):

One whose relative is buried on Chol HaMoed must observe a full 30 days of Sheloshim starting from the funeral, with Shiva only taking place after the holiday is over ([Shulchan Aruch YD 399:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9732&st=&pgnum=619)).